# How to pass server value to client javascript in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I rendered view with one variable and want to use the variable in javascript file included rendered view.
I use pug view template

```
**Server Side.**

res.render('myView', { myval:'pizza'});

**Client Side**

extends ../layout

block content
  script(src="scripts/myscript.js")

**myscript.js**

$(function(){
   alert(myval);
});

or 

**index.pug**

    script(type='text/javascript').
    var val= '#{myval}';
    alert(val);
```

how to do it? looking forward any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view `myView` you need to render that value in js block.

```
script(type='text/javascript')
    var myval = '#{myval}';
```

It will be visible in your script.

Comment: And what about alert? Does it display proper value?

Comment: oh everything is ok.
I set enctype of form as multipart/form-data.

Comment: I changed it as application/x-www-form-urlencoded and it work well.
Thanks.
Btw, what is difference between '#{myval}' and '!{myval}'?

Comment: ```#{myval}``` is evaluated & escaped. ```!{myval}``` is evaluated and unescaped. So if you want to do ```myval = '#{myval}'``` you need to escape string, because if you don't using string with ```'``` will break your code. https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html